# How to make an object appear and disappear repeatedly in a certain area?

Tags: scripting, physics, visibility

I am animating an atom and I don't want to use a Bohr model so I am trying to make radials. For this, I need to define a boundary, and then have an electron (shown as a sphere) to appear and disappear repeatedly in a random spot within the boundary. I don't really want to make a bunch of objects and animate the visibility, but I can if there is no other options. This is for a animation, so I would prefer a solution that isn't in BGE. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a particle system, defining the boundary by the shape of the emitter.

To  make 1 particle appear and disappear in random places, set the lifetime of the particle to be the desired frame length of its appearance, and set the total number of particles to divide the total duration of emission by that amount.

Switch off physics, velocities, etc, set the Emit From to 'Volume', and make a sphere to be the target 'Object' of the render settings.

Sample settings:

[image]

Sample Result:

[image]

You could animate the object color, for example, to have each electron fade in and out, or produce other effects.

Answer (score 0):

you could create a material with the material you are already using, connected to a mix shader with a transparent shader, with a factor or one or zero (depending on which shader is on top), and keyframe the factor to one frame before it dissapears. then in the next frame, change the factor to 0 or 1 (the opposite of what you had it on before) and then keyframe the factor again. that way, it will look as if it is dissapearing. You can then move it around, and then change back the factor.